# i want make my view transparent so that form present view the previous view should me slightly visible

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i want make my view transparent show the the previous view will slightly visible,i tried something below but it is not working , i am using interface builder to create view,please help me out.

```
@implementation CylinderBoresTotal

(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];


self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.alpha = 0.2;
self.view.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working" ? What happens when you set, for example, `[UIColor redColor]`?

Comment: i want to previous xib's view should be visible....i tried but previous view not visible....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is something underneath the `self.view` ?

Views from another UIViewController is not underneath the CylinderBoresTotal's `self.view`

You may capture the image of that view first, and insert it into your current view instead. (expensive)

Comment: yah there is one more view before that class ........ and  thanks i got the clue ..... ok let me try .......